# How do I put two huge pictures on the same page?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I am looking to print these pictures on the same page so that I can cut them out. It would be fine if there's no space between them horizontally. Bonus points for trim marks!

M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=18cm,height=13cm]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=18cm,height=13cm]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To add trim marks, put `\llap{\rule{1em}{0.7pt} \hspace{\linewidth}}\rlap{ \rule{1em}{0.7pt}}\\[-\lineskip]` at the end of the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this line into your preamble:

```
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\vspace{-3cm}
\makebox[0pt]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{18cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=13cm]{example-image-a}\\[-\lineskip]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=13cm]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that it's important to maintain the aspect ratio of the images. I so, I suggest you replace the options

```
width=18cm, height=13cm
```

with

```
width=\textwidth, height=0.475\textheight, keepaspectratio
```

Of course, you can (and probably should) also set the values of `\textwidth` and `\textheight`. To set them indirectly, you could load the `geometry` package with, say, the following options:

```
\usepackage[margin=1mm,a4paper]{geometry}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1mm,a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p!]
%\caption{Hello World} % <-- optional

\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.475\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.475\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```